# How to show time-breakdown × availability from multiple parties in Web App?

Tags: web-app, tables, responsive-design, calendar, timeline

I'm designing an scheduling application and I would like to know what's the most intuitive way to display the info of time-breakdown × availability from multiple parties.

Below shows my current design for the availability of instructor, venue & class on a certain day:-

[image]

Each hour is breakdown into 6 chunks while red & green colors indicate whether the corresponding resource is available or not.

For example, the specified **Instructor** was available after 8:00 am while the specified **Venue** was unavailable from 7:30 am to 8:30 am.

As you might already noticed the table shown is kinda confusing and not accurate since the precision is 10 minutes (i.e., 7:15 am to 8:00 am would turn the 2nd row to 6th row in the table in red). I hope I'm able split the hour further but it seems 10 mins is a good balance to prevent cluttering user's screen. (this was shown in web + mobile app)

May I know what's the alternative way to show this kinda of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proposal is clear. Some ideas:

- use the same width for the columns
- put the number in the middle of the line
- the hour could be introduced in the minutes column
- you could add extra lines for 5 minutes, without numbers, then the block could start/end there if necessary without much confusion

[image]

Comment: Yup you're right! You nailed the fact that the time display should act as a **boundary** instead of a "cell unit" to indicate the time range. Appreciate your idea!

Comment: @Zephyr you are welcome! You expressed it much better than I did :) using boundaries can give more precision to the start/end of the range.